# Block Longlistselector from loading items

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I'm making a Windows phone 8 app and I have to use longlistselector to display items as list and grid. I have a "update" button. It can reload item list (delete all existing items and then load others (new items))

My problem is: If I tap update button when Longlistselector is displaying items on phone's screen, it delete all existing items and it continues load the rest items and it also load new (updated) items. The list become a mess.

I find no way to stop or block longlist selector from loading items, so I post my question to here, and hope someone can help me.

Thanks you guys very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean that is set to true when data-loading begins and set to false when data loading is complete. Then have the code that reacts to the button press only work if the boolean is false, when data isn't being loaded in.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but the problem is: the data is loaded very fast, but the UI is not. I want reload the list when it is still rendering UI, for now if I delete data source or items the UI is still rendering and I get a mess. I want to find a way to kill it's UI thread, but I can't do that for now